# Spring Boot - Externalizar as configurações do banco de dados

Tags: spring-boot, configuração

Tenho um projeto JAVA desenvolvido com o Spring Boot.

As configurações do banco de dados estão no arquivo padrão **resources/application.properties**.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.********:1521/BDHML
spring.datasource.username=********
spring.datasource.password=********
```

A aplicação irá rodar através do comando:

```
java -jar **CONFIGURAÇÃO** app-cosolidar.jar
```

Preciso colocar as configurações do banco de dados em um arquivo .properties externo ao projeto.

Como posso fazer isso?

Como deve ser o arquivo .properties?

Devo alterar algum arquivo .java?

Qual a configuração que devo colocar no java -jar?

Obrigado,

Diego

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi criando um arquivo chamado **application.properties**, onde estão as configurações do **spring.datasource**.

Depois, criei um script da seguinte forma:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_DIR=${PWD}
ADDITIONAL_APP_PROPERTIES="${BASE_DIR}/application.properties"    # Configuracoes da aplicacao - Spring Boot

java -Dspring.config.additional-location=${ADDITIONAL_APP_PROPERTIES} \
  -jar ${BASE_DIR}/app-cosolidar.jar
```

O arquivo JAR está funcionando corretamente dessa forma.